# Why is glibc's sscanf vastly slower than fscanf on Linux?

Tags: c, performance, glibc, scanf

I am using GCC 4.8 and glibc 2.19 on an x86_64 Linux.

While playing with different input methods for [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23922606/596781), I compared `fscanf` and `sscanf`. Specifically, I would either use `fscanf` on the standard input directly:

```
char s[128]; int n;

while (fscanf(stdin, "%127s %d", s, &n) == 2) { }
```

Or I would first read the entire input into a buffer and then traverse the buffer with `sscanf`. (Reading everything into the buffer takes a tiny amount of time.)

```
char s[128]; int n;
char const * p = my_data;

for (int b; sscanf(p, "%127s %d%n", s, &n, &b) == 2; p += b) { }
```

To my surprise, the `fscanf` version is *vastly* faster. For example, processing seveal tens of thousands of lines with `fscanf` takes this long:

```
10000       0.003927487 seconds time elapsed
20000       0.006860206 seconds time elapsed
30000       0.007933329 seconds time elapsed
40000       0.012881912 seconds time elapsed
50000       0.013516816 seconds time elapsed
60000       0.015670432 seconds time elapsed
70000       0.017393129 seconds time elapsed
80000       0.019837480 seconds time elapsed
90000       0.023925753 seconds time elapsed
```

Now the same with `sscanf`:

```
10000       0.035864643 seconds time elapsed
20000       0.127150772 seconds time elapsed
30000       0.319828373 seconds time elapsed
40000       0.611551668 seconds time elapsed
50000       0.919187459 seconds time elapsed
60000       1.327831544 seconds time elapsed
70000       1.809843039 seconds time elapsed
80000       2.354809588 seconds time elapsed
90000       2.970678416 seconds time elapsed
```

I was using the Google perf tools to measure this. For example, for 50000 lines, the `fscanf` code requires about 50M cycles, and the `sscanf` code about 3300M cycles. So I broke down the top call sites with `perf record`/`perf report`. With `fscanf`:

```
 35.26%  xf  libc-2.19.so         [.] _IO_vfscanf
 23.91%  xf  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] 0xffffffff8104f45a
  8.93%  xf  libc-2.19.so         [.] _int_malloc
```

And with `sscanf`:

```
 98.22%  xs  libc-2.19.so         [.] rawmemchr
  0.68%  xs  libc-2.19.so         [.] _IO_vfscanf
  0.38%  xs  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] 0xffffffff8104f45a
```

So almost all of the time with `sscanf` is spent in `rawmemchr`! Why is this? How can the `fscanf` code avoid this cost?

I tried searching for this, but the best I could come up with is [this discussion](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2012-05/msg00017.html) of locked `realloc` calls which I don't think applies here. I was also thinking that `fscanf` has better memory locality (using the same buffer over and over), but that can't make such a big difference.

Does anyone have any insights in this strange discrepancy?

Comment: Complete code for: [`fscanf`](https://ideone.com/sIr8lN), [`sscanf`](http://ideone.com/R8SQeJ)

Comment: I have trouble finding the source code for `_IO_vfscanf`. [This](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-934.3/libio/iovfscanf.c) is the best I could find, but that isn't necessarily glibc 2.19.

Comment: Show the loop processing - it looks like you have a ["Schlemiel the Painter" problem](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I linked the test code, and have posted the loops in the question. Do you think `sscanf` scans to the end of the string each time? That would contradict the value stored in `b`, which has the expected value (i.e. one line of input is consumed in each call).

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Actually, I think Michael Burr is right, it appears that `sscanf` is searching the _entire file_ for the trailing null, and then parsing out the three variables you want.  Look at the example on http://linux.die.net/man/3/rawmemchr

Comment: @MichaelBurr: He does, but the Schlemiel the Painter Problem seems to be in glibc itself, not in OP's code.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

sscanf() converts the string you pass in to an `_IO_FILE*` to make the string look like a "file". This is so the same internal _IO_vfscanf() can be used for both a string and a FILE*.

However, as part of that conversion, done in a _IO_str_init_static_internal() function, it calls `__rawmemchr (ptr, '\0');` essentially a strlen() call, on your input string. This conversion is done on every call to sscanf(), and since your input buffer is rather large, it'll spend a fair amount of time calculating the length of the input string.

Creating a FILE* from the input string using fmemopen() and use fscanf() could be another alternative.

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug report against glibc. This issue could definitely be fixed in principle by making the virtual `FILE` provided by `sscanf` use custom ops that don't require advance knowledge of the string length. Actually our implementation in musl libc avoids the issue, so I know it's possible. :-)

Comment: @R..: I had never heard of musl before -- thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 8):

It looks like glibc's `sscanf()` scans the source string for the length before doing anything else.

`sscanf()` (in `stdio-common/sscanf.c`) is essentially a wrapper around a call to `_IO_vsscanf()` (in `libio/iovsscanf.c`).  And one of the first things that `_IO_vsscanf()` does is initialize its own `_IO_strfile` structure by calling `_IO_str_init_static_internal()` (in `libio/strops.c`) which calculates the length of the string if it's not provided.